# How to use an external disk to boot to Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup

I want to be able to boot into windows. I only have 256GB on my Mac, and my current windows C: drive has over 112 GB in it used. So I would like to keep the on-board SDD free for OS X.

Is it possible to have an external USB 3.0 drive and boot to that to get windows? If so, what advice should I follow?

TIA
Mark

Comment: I'm interested in. Did you find an answer?

Comment: I ended up using Parallels, which my wife was using on her school-provided Macbook Air. It seemed to to the job. And the VM file was on the main disk as well, because the machine is not too full yet.

Sorry I couldn't give you a better answer.